# Spring MVC: What is an attribute?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

The `Model` interface has the term attribute. An example of this is the  `addAttribute()` method. What does attribute mean in this context?

Comment: Please leave a comment about the downvote.

Comment: You mean the variable name `attributeName` and `attributeValue`? Or what is your real question?

Comment: @radlabman are you talking about the old `addObject()` method on `ModelMap`? It's very unclear what you're asking right now, so this is probably the reason your question is downvoted. Or is your question why the method was called `addAttibute()`  in stead of something else?

Comment: @g00glen00b I have edited the question please reconsider.

Comment: @Patrick I ask about the meaning of the term attribute itself

Comment: Still a weird question, the `addAttribute()` does what the method itself says, it adds an attribute/property to the model which you can then use in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the answer/comments. I found the answer a day later in this link http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-tld.html

It turns out that the term "attribute" from the `Model` interface refers to the attributes of the JSP tags such as the `param` tag with the attributes `name` and `value`.

Comment: i have no idea why i got downvoted and not being chosen as the correct answer?

Answer (score -1):

Not so sure what you have asked but i do have comment or "answer" to your question.

Object has several "attribute"s ,

For instance, for a "circle object"

has

"area","circumference","radius"  attributes.

Quote from wiki:

Object-oriented programming (OOP) is a programming paradigm based on the concept of "objects", which may contain data, in the form of fields, often known as attributes; and code, in the form of procedures, often known as methods. A feature of objects is that an object's procedures can access and often modify the data fields of the object with which they are associated (objects have a notion of "this" or "self"). In OOP, computer programs are designed by making them out of objects that interact with one another.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)[2] There is significant diversity of OOP languages, but the most popular ones are class-based, meaning that objects are instances of classes, which typically also determine their type.

Many of the most widely used programming languages are multi-paradigm programming languages that support object-oriented programming to a greater or lesser degree, typically in combination with imperative, procedural programming. Significant object-oriented languages include Java, C++, C#, Python, PHP, Ruby, Perl, Delphi, Objective-C, Swift, Common Lisp, and Smalltalk.

For more info: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)